# Point for Each Parcel on the Road in front with angle information

Tags: google-street-view

I have this interesting problem and hope someone can provide some insight/solution. I have access to full blown ESRI software.

I have property parcels layer with close to 20,000 records. The attributes of this layer contains regular parcel info, plus addresses. There are three separate columns for addressing; Street Number, Street Name, and Full Address.

I want to place a point right at the centre front of each parcel, preferably on the Road line feature that I have. In case where the the parcel is on the corner and has access to more than one road, I want to place the point on the road that matches with the address. Finally for each point I need an xy coordinate and an angle for facing the front of the parcel.

This data will then be used by a developer to incorporate Google Street View with a property information application.

Does anyone have some ideas as to what would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: How are you looking to define the point in front of a property? Do you have rules for governing how curves in the parcel boundary / road are handled?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't.

Comment: It is a tricky problem. A simple perpendicular line from the road centreline to the centre of the parcel will work great when there are no curves in the road and the parcels are regular shape. But considerations need to be made for irregular parcels, pan-handles, cul-de-sacs and bends in the road. It may be worthwhile looking into converting the parcel to segmented polylines, assigning the address t  the polyline closest to the road and generating a centroid along that polyline. I am not sure where to start, but it is an avenue to consider.

Comment: Would the 'NEAR' tool do anything? or any other proximity analysis methods?

Comment: The NEAR Tool may work in some cases. But there is a strong likelihood that the tool will mis-report relationships if the plots are rotated, pan-handle or there are more than one roads / centrelines in close proximity to  the plot (like corner plots).

Comment: Is there a way to modify Near Tool? What I'm thinking is since the parcels have address field and streetName field, would it be possible to modify the Near Tool in a way where it only selects the roads where the name matches with the name of the street in the parcel?

Comment: It could be possible to run a select by attribute first, using the road name as a guide for the selection. Then run a NEAR process, this will force the tool to only look at the selected features. I no longer have access to ESRI software, so I cannot test code for you, but it is pretty easy in Python to set up a script to do this (the selection and then NEAR run, the remainder of the question still has a lot of work to get through).